# NPM - Requiring parent dependency

Tags: node.js, npm

So I have this:

```
// package.json:
{
  "name": "x",
  "dependencies": {
    "y": "latest",
    "z": "latest"
  }
}
```

my question is - **can y and z reliably require x, or should I pass the path of x to y and z, and have them require that path?** I assume the latter is the most reliable way to ensure that y and z both see the same version of x, etc. I do not want y and z to have to depend on x directly, because I want to ensure they use the same version of x.

Comment: npm's new `package.lock` should solve this

Comment: thanks can you explain how

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but are you describing a circular dependency?

Comment: Yes that's right  - x requires y and z, and y and z need to load x. it's not that I am worried that a circular dependency is going to break something, it's more that I want to ensure the same exact version of x is used, and that the code represented by x does not need to be loaded more than once. If two different versions of x are present (two different paths), x will be loaded more than once.

Comment: To be exact, I do not want y and z to declare x as a dependency for more than one reason, but the primary reasons are because I want the same version of x used everywhere, and I don't want to load x more than once. so I pass x to y and z, instead of having y and z directly depend on x.

Comment: reliably on NPM to get this right is fallible, especially since this is library code, and some users might be using older versions of NPM.

Comment: I see.  To be honest, trying to hack a circular dependency like this will probably lead to madness down the line - I'm not even sure how it could be made to work!  It may well be worth seeing if there's a way to tweak your architecture to avoid this entirely.

Comment: Oh, I think it's very simple. I just pass the dependency from one project to the other. Loading the dependency in two separate places is just a simple recipe for having two different versions of the same dependency. passing the dependency over, is sort of a DI thing at work, I guess. the original question was more about how NPM works.